# Register multiple RedirectUris

Tags: openiddict

Sometimes a client has more than one redirect uri. We want to be able to register multiple `RedirectUri` values. How, if at all, do we do that?

```
context.Applications.Add(new OpenIddictApplication
{
    ClientId = "zamboni-app",
    ClientSecret = Crypto.HashPassword("secret_secret_secret"),
    DisplayName = "Zamboni app",
    LogoutRedirectUri = "http://zamboni-app.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc",
    RedirectUri = "http://zamboni-app.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc",
    Type = OpenIddictConstants.ClientTypes.Public
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** support for multiple `redirect_uri` has been added in the RTM version of OpenIddict. My original recommendation still applies: please don't use this ability to create "mega clients" that span multiple domains/security boundaries.

---

Specifying multiple `redirect_uri` is deliberately not supported by OpenIddict to deter you from reusing the same client registration (read `client_id`) for all your apps.

Comment: How are we meant to handle a client application moving from one domain to another if we cannot have both as valid redirect uris? (We want to check everything works on the new domain before everyone moves over to using it).

Comment: @Lukazoid you can't downvote an answer just because you disapprove a design decision and expect an answer to your question.

Comment: That's okay, I figured out a solution on my own. I downvoted your answer because I didn't find it useful. At least I left a comment explaining why I don't feel it is a useful answer. I'm sorry you took my downvote so personally.

Comment: lol, I didn't take it personally. I just pointed out the fact that downvoting an answer and asking a question to its author at the same time seems self-contradictory. My answer reflects "why" there's no built-in support for multiple redirections URLs and the GitHub thread where you found the `ValidateRedirectUriAsync` trick mentions a concrete case explaining why having multiple `redirect_uri` is not advised. If you want to shoot yourself in the foot, that's your problem, not mine. Just note that `ValidateRedirectUriAsync` might be removed at any time.

Comment: Ah, it felt like you were saying you were refusing to help me because I downvoted the answer, hence I thought it was personal. Could you possibly update your answer with some justification of why multiple redirect URIs is a bad thing? I feel that would make it much more useful and help guide us less knowledgable in the right direction.

Comment: @Lukazoid the reason is already mentioned: to deter you from using the same client registration for multiple apps (or multiple environments like production/testing). Now, if you wonder why doing that is not good from a security perspective, feel free to open a separate question. I'll edit my post to mention it when it's answered.

Comment: @KévinChalet So this is supported now, right?  `public HashSet<Uri> RedirectUris { get; }`

Comment: @01F0 it is, but the only case where I'd ever use that is for SPA apps that have a separate callback page for silent authorization responses. And since it's a scenario that will no longer work due to the 3rd party cookie ban in most browsers, well... 

Comment: Thanks for following up!  We have a server where we want several devs to be able to test the flow against with their local redirect_uris ..  But I definitely see you points and I will replace it in the near future!

Comment: @KévinChalet What about BFF. We have multitenat app where each tenant works on own subdomain. App means BFF is only one. What about redirects to all possible subdomains?

Comment: @KévinChalet Can you help me with my question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673067/refresh-token-using-implicit-flow-openiddict"

I don`t understand how to specify correct redirect uri when use prompt = none and Implicit Flow.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a requirement for this when a client application needs to be accessible from multiple domains (there's a reason most OAuth providers allow this).

You can allow multiple redirect URIs for a client application by creating a new class derived from `OpenIddictApplicationManager<TApplication>` and overriding the `ValidateRedirectUriAsync` method:

```
public sealed class MyApplicationManager : OpenIddictApplicationManager<MyApplication>
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override Task<bool> ValidateRedirectUriAsync(MyApplication application, string address, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var validRedirectUris = application.RedirectUris.Select(u => u.Uri);
        if(validRedirectUris.Contains(address, StringComparer.Ordinal))
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        return Task.FromResult(false);
    }
}
```

In this example, `MyApplication` has an additional field which contains the redirect URIs, this could be a relationship to another entity in the database.

Then be sure to register this application manager like so:

```
services.AddOpenIddict<MyApplication, OpenIdAuthorization, OpenIdScope, OpenIdToken>()
    .AddApplicationManager<MyApplicationManager>();
```

Comment: `there's a reason most OAuth providers allow this` is an unfounded assertion. Major providers like Facebook, Reddit, Dropbox or Box don't allow you to register multiple callback addresses. And yeah, there's a reason for that, too.

Comment: But facebook allows multiple redirect URIs, I've not looked at the others yet.

Comment: Only if you use the advanced options. Otherwise, only one address is allowed.